# output file with names from groupby results pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {'READID': [1,1,1  ,1,1    ,5,5    ,5,5],
  'VG': ['LV5-F*01','LV5-F*01'  ,'LV5-F*01','LV5-F*01','LV5-F*01','LV5-A*01','LV5-A*01','LV5-A*01','LV5-A*01'],
  'Pro': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

it looks like :

```
df
Out[23]: 
     Pro  READID     VG
0    1       1   LV5-F*01
1    1       1   LV5-F*01
2    1       1   LV5-F*01
3    1       1   LV5-F*01
4    1       1   LV5-F*01
5    2       5   LV5-A*01
6    2       5   LV5-A*01
7    2       5   LV5-A*01
8    2       5   LV5-A*01
```

This is a sample dataset, the actual dataset contains many more columns and many many more rows with different combinations for the groupby, i want to groupby the 3 columns and output individual separate files with the VG as part of its name:

desired output:

```
'LV5-F*01.txt':

     Pro  READID     VG
0    1       1   LV5-F*01
1    1       1   LV5-F*01
2    1       1   LV5-F*01
3    1       1   LV5-F*01
4    1       1   LV5-F*01

'LV5-A*01.txt':

    Pro  READID     VG
5    2       5   LV5-A*01
6    2       5   LV5-A*01
7    2       5   LV5-A*01
8    2       5   LV5-A*01
```

My attempt:

```
(df.groupby(['READID','VG','Pro'])
.apply(lambda gp: gp.to_csv('{}.txt'.format(gp.VG.name), sep='\t', index=False))
 )
```

however, the

```
  '{}.txt'.format(gp.VG.name)
```

part only produced a file named 'VG.txt' containing only 1 line which is not what i want.

Comment: giving me error: which error?

Comment: please see my 'edit' @Jean-François Fabre

Comment: Why don't you use a regular loop instead of apply?

Comment: i can use a regular loop but what goes in the place of ''{}.txt'.format(gp.VG.name)' ?   it is obviously not giving me the names of the VG values.  @ayhan

Comment: Use `gp.VG.iloc[0]` instead of `gp.VG.name` if you want the VG value.

Comment: @root  error says  AtributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: If you iterate over a regular loop than it will return a tuple, that tuples first element will be for VG. `grp[0][1]`

Comment: @ayhan  can you write an answer? i am a beginner and i'm not very good at syntax, i tried  for g in dp.group:
    g.to_cvs('{}.txt'.format(g[0][1].name), sep='\t', index=False))   which failed.

Comment: @Jessica: Do you still have a `.name` on there?  It should just end in `.iloc[0]` with no `.name`.  With just `.iloc[0]` it works for me, and the error you mentioned doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = df.groupby(['READID','VG','Pro'])
for group in g:
    group[1].to_csv('{}.txt'.format(group[0][1]), sep='\t', index=False)
```

You might want to strip `*` character if it causes problems.

Also note that you group on three keys but using only one key as the file name. It may overwrite other files with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need groupby, you can just select the rows you need and convert them to text file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'READID': [1,1,1  ,1,1    ,5,5    ,5,5],
  'VG': ['LV5-F*01','LV5-F*01'  ,'LV5-F*01','LV5-F*01','LV5-F*01','LV5-A*01','LV5-A*01','LV5-A*01','LV5-A*01'],
  'Pro': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

with open('LV5-F*01.txt', 'w') as fil:
    fil.write(df[df['VG'] == 'LV5-F*01'].to_string())

with open('LV5-A*01.txt', 'w') as fil:
    fil.write(df[df['VG'] == 'LV5-A*01'].to_string())
```

Comment: my actual file contains 1 millions lines with millions of combinations for the groupby

Comment: ah i see, that would be a problem :-)

Comment: can you actually open a file containing `*` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes it is possible

Comment: Not on windows it's not.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah that might be true, it works on mac.